# Error while freeing a malloc'd pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm getting an error while freeing a malloc'd string in the following piece of code:

```
long authenticate(char* user, long* uid, long* gid){
FILE* fp = fopen("/etc/passwd", "r");
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
long lineSize;
char* uname;

if (fp == NULL)
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  while ((lineSize = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

    uname = (char*)malloc(lineSize*sizeof(char));
    getInfo(line, lineSize, &uname, &uid, &gid);

    if(strcmp(uname, user) == 0) {  // Strings are equal
      printf("we've found a user!\n");
      printf("uname: %s uid: %ld gid: %ld\n", uname, *uid, *gid);
      free(uname);
      exit(1);
    }

    free(uname);
  }
}
```

Whenever I find a valid username, free `uname` and then exit nothing happens. However, when I don't find a valid `uname` (if statement doesn't get evaluated) when I try to free `uname` at the end of the loop I get the following error:

> malloc: *** error for object 0x10d20ef2c: pointer being freed was not allocated

I don't understand why free() is not registering that `uname` was previously malloc'd. Given the nature of the bug, I believe the problem is me not understanding something about `malloc`/`free`.

Comment: Compile your code with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use `gdb`  and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to debug it. BTW `uname` is a POSIX function, so better use some other name.

Comment: Off-by-one: `getline()` returns the number of characters in the buffer *excluding* the terminating `'\0'`. Your malloc'ed buffer is too small. The rest might simply be the result of UB.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the name. When I step through it with gdb I get a segfault on strcmp :(

Comment: I'm not sure about what the `getInfo` is doing internally but chances are, it is probably tweaking the value of `uname` (that is, changing the address stored via `uname++`, for example).

Comment: @dhke getline() actually accounts for the extra character

Comment: I guess the problem is that iff you don't find the username you'll eventually reach the last line of `/etc/passwd` which is empty (under unix, most files end with an linebreak) and you malloc 0 bytes.

Comment: Post the getInfo() function definition.

Comment: @tonocm In allocating the buffer into `line`, yes. But the returned size is only for the line up and including the line delimiter, [*excluding*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) the terminator. The `malloc()`d buffer might actually be to small by one character, depending on what `getInfo()` does. Try comparing `len` and `lineSize`. But after more reading, it's probably `getInfo()` that does the actual damage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, most likely, that `getInfo()` modifies where `uname` points to, after which it isn't recognized by `free()`.

Comment: You're right, inside getInfo() I had an equal statement instead of strncpy(). Might it be that strings are allocated differently if I have, say:

char* str = malloc(...);
strncpy(str, otherStr, i);

or

char* str = malloc(...);
str = "something";

Comment: @tonocom Sorry, don't think I understood the question. Rephrase?

Comment: @tonocm `char* str = malloc(...); str = "something";` would totally blow away the address of the memory you just allocated to `str`. Instead, what  you want to do is put data into that allocated memory, which is pointed by `str`, this is done by `strcpy(str,"something");`